# Problems with Chrome and http POST over https

Tags: google-chrome, post, https

my company's website is experiencing problems with Chrome when users use POST actions (forms and XHR) over https. In most cases the response never arrives. The app server logs the responses as 200, though.

The problem never occurs with local (non-https) instances, and I can only reproduce it with certain settings (typically access from inside firewalled networks).

Did that problem occur to anybody else ? Maybe Chrome has problems with SSL handshakes over such firewalled settings ?

**Edit**:
The problem could be solved by updating lighttpd to the latest version.

Comment: Does this help? http://code.google.com/p/cherokee/issues/detail?id=1284

Comment: No, not really - we use lighttpd in front of Apache/Rails, that post deals with a bug in Cherokee.. The comments are rather confusing.. is google intentionally making changes that force everybody to change some configuration details on their servers, or is there a SSL misconfiguration from our side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be solved by updating lighttpd to the latest version.

Comment: Same here, fixed by updating from 1.4.28 to 1.4.31.